# How to force application using localhost:9000 to shut down

Tags: networking, localhost

So I'm not the smartes fellow when it comes to ports and networks and things like that, maybe why I now is in this situation.

So I'm trying to connect to localhost:9000 with a AngularJS project I have, only to get the message that I'm unable to connect.

I've tried the command `netstat -an` but alas I don't understand any of what it's telling me. Is there a way to force whatever i running on localhost:9000 to stop so that I can use it for something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lsof` to find the process using port 9000.

```
lsof -i :9000
kill <pid>
```

For Windows, you will want to run `netstat -ano | findstr :9000`.  The number to the far right will be the PID of the process you want to kill.

Comment: when using lsof the command can't be found. I'm working on Windows 8

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard On Windows you will want to run `netstat -ano | findstr :9000`.  The number on the far right is the PID of the process you will want to kill.

Comment: hmm I must be doing something wrong, when calling `netstat -ano | findstr :9000` I get no result

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard Are you sure that there is a process using port 9000?  I'm not familiar with AngularJS myself, but it doesn't sound like a process running on port 9000 is your issue.

Comment: After a lot of work I've found that the problem was in my `mongoose.schema`. Thanks for the help ^^